# Is there a way in Amibroker backtest to specify buy price?

Tags: amibroker

Is there a way to place buy order at a certain value?

I am trying to buy at the break of previous day high on a 5 min tf:

```
DayH = TimeFrameGetPrice("H", inDaily, -1); // yesterdays high
DayL = TimeFrameGetPrice("L", inDaily, -1); // low
DayC = TimeFrameGetPrice("C", inDaily, -1); // close
DayO = TimeFrameGetPrice("O", inDaily); // current day open

Buy = H >= DayH AND DayO < DayH;
BuyPrice = DayH;
```

But I am not able to get the buy price similar to yesterday's high, its always something more or less

Answer (score 0):

Use SetTradeDelays()

```
Buy = High
SetTradeDelays(-1,-1,-1,-1);
```